# RWDBReader Cannot read more than 255 characters

Tags: c++, database, limit, rogue-wave, character-limit

We're using Rogue Wave tools for our database operations, writing in C++. When we try to read the results of a simple SQL query, like:

```
RWDBResult  resParam = VimerParamTblSlc.execute (pConn);

RWDBTable resultParam = resParam.table ();
RWDBReader rdrParam = resultParam.reader ();
if (rdrParam()) 
{
    // getting the resulting row fro, the reader
}
```

If the result contains more than 255 characters, then the reader (rdrParam) doesn't load the row at all, I mean it can't pass the if condition.

Is there a way to set this character limit for reading? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We learn that it was a version problem with the adaptive server of Sybase and not RogueWave's fault. You need both the adaptive server and Open Client of version 12.5(or later).